# How to switch to Haskell Interactive and reload last line in emacs?

Tags: haskell, emacs

Is there a command available to load the the current buffer to the haskell process and execute the previous line I introduced in the ghci?
I am trying to make a function for this, but I get "Unexpected response from haskell process." because of this line: haskell-interactive-mode-history-previous

```
 (defun reload-haskell-last-line () (interactive)
  "blablabla"
  (haskell-process-load-file)
  (haskell-interactive-switch)
  (haskell-interactive-mode-history-previous)
  (haskell-interactive-mode-return)
  )
```

This can be super handy for developing.
If this is not the right way, what do you usually use?
Atom haskell-ide repl has a similar feature, that I would like to replicate in emacs

Comment: What version of GHC? It could be related to this bug: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/1553

Comment: Exactly that version - 8.2.1